RHEL8 + GNOME: PC unresponsive on Activities overview page (mouse and keyboard interactions not working)
My desktop PC is running RHEL8 with GNOME, and I am encountering a weird issue where, if I move windows around too quickly on the Activities overview page, the PC becomes unresponsive. My mouse cursor can still move around on the screen, but I am unable to click on anything and as far as I can tell, typing on my keyboard does nothing. I am stuck on that Activities overview page, and have to forcibly restart my desktop to resolve the issue.
This has already happened 2-3 times this past month, so advice on what is going on and what I can do about it would be much appreciated
